# When I use uniq -u I get no outpput, but why?

Tags: linux, command

When I run the following command, I expect to get the ip addresses of ASG member instances:

```
current_servers=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names "${asgname}" --region $region | grep InstanceId | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d '\"|,' | tr -d '\n') --region $region | grep "PrivateIpAddress" | grep -v '\[' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | uniq -u | tr -d '\"|,' )
```

For some reason, the I get no output.

But if I change the `uniq -u` command to just `uniq`, then I get the correct output.

From uniq's man:

```
-u, --unique
              only print unique lines
```

Without the uniq command, the output is:

```
 172.51.39.73
 172.51.39.73
 172.51.39.73
```

So it seems (by uniq's man) that if I want to get only one occurrence of the output I have to use `uniq -u`.

Anyone knows why the command acts like that? that is giving me no output if I use the "-u" switch?

Comment: can you check if there are end of line chars there? I think in this case uniq needs a sort.

Comment: No, there's no space at the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what `uniq` does. Without the `-u` switch, it combines multiple subsequent (!) identical lines into one line, and with the `-u` switch it omits these lines (as they are not uniqe):

```
sven@linux:~$ cat uniq.txt
Line1            ## these two lines are not unique. 
Line1
Line2
Line1
sven@linux:~$ uniq uniq.txt
Line1
Line2
Line1
sven@linux:~$ uniq -u uniq.txt
Line2
Line1
```

So, in your case, since your IP address is repeated two times, it will not be shown with the `-u` switch and this is normal (but not very intuitive, as it is often the case with these kind of tools).

Comment: Is there a better tool for this?

Comment: Define better. As far as I understand it, `uniq` without `-u` does exactly what you want.